# How to protect footvalve from sticking open by sediment?

Tags: well, well-pump

Of late there is seepage of surface water into my open well. This is further aggravated by agglomeration of decaying leaves from a neem tree over the well itself. Its an old well - about 30ft across - beyond my resources to cover it; Besides leaves are not the only issue. As a consequence,  every few days I would lose prime on the pump. I suspect part of the seepage is ground movement on account of earthworks to construct a flyover, and other highrise buildings in the neighbourhood.

The pump itself is an open well self priming type which has served  almost faultlessly o er 2 decades. The outlet is bifurcated; my temporary solution has been to run the ground floor pipe back into the well parallel to the footvalve. This works for now because the ground floor does not need water much, and perhaps because the sediment in the well is not so dense.

If the density ever increases, how do I prevent the footvalve from sticking open?

Comment: A 30 foot / 9 meter wide open well sounds more like a pond. How deep is it? Where's the water level relative to the ground surface?

Comment: Old old old well. I haven't sounded it for depth. As best as I recall from conversation( the well predates my parents too ) it goes down nearly 60 ft if their source be believed. Well level is around 10ft from the lip since seepage began.

Answer (score 1):

I pump from creeks and ponds throughout the year they make metal cages that go around the foot valve and because they are quite a bit larger they don’t easily plug up with leaves , one I have a rope on that if it plugs up I turn the pump off jerk the rope a couple of times and all the excess falls off the cage, my suction line is 3” but the cage is close to 8” in diameter and probably 4” tall, the cages or strainer last about 10 years even in mud it keeps the foot out of the mud and any grass and leaves out of the foot, maybe 2x per year I have to move it to dislodge the leaves that settle on it some years only 1 move is needed. You could even make one out of galvanized mesh like is used on the top of chimneys, I did that a few years back but it only lasted ~3 years.

Comment: Pretty much the same approach :)